# Pandas referencing and indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, reference

Consider I have dataframe as:

> ```
>   Name Visits
> 0 A      0
> 1 B      0
> 2 C      0
> 3 D      0
> 4 E      0
> ```

Now, I want to change the visits of only E or any other specific person to any random number, how do I do it? Like how do I specifically refer the visits of any single person, say E and change their visits? I tried reading the documentation, but it does not help. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loc and numpy's randint function:

```
# change the randint range to whatever you want
df.loc[df['Name'] == 'E', 'Visits'] = np.random.randint(0,100)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, works like a charm! Will vote it as the answer in 7 minutes. I have another small offtopic doubt, would you please answer it as a reply in this comment section?

Comment: Sure, what is your question?

Comment: Suppose I have an excel file names "ABC.xlsx". I read this as a dataframe(df) in my program using pd.read_excel. Now I make certain changes in this df data frame. And by certain changes, I mean stuff like changing the visits of certain people, as I asked in the question above. Is there a way I make sure whatever changes I make to this df are also reflected in the original excel file? Or do I have to save this df as an excel file with the same name to overwrite it?

Comment: The easiest thing to do would be to just overwrite the file using `df.to_excel(...)`; however, you could also look into using [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)